# Check user permissions in RESTful API

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization, jwt

I'm developing a SaaS API with NodeJS, Express, MongoDB. It has implemented a JWT authentication/security methodology.

In my personal case, I have (for now) two collections: User and Client.

[image]

You can see the fields that each collection has (for defining purposes). So in terms of endpoint design I'm using a trully restful approach so:

- /api/users/{userId}/clients: to insert clients i.e.

This is exactly the point I'm bringing I want, that before posting a new client to check if the price plan allows the user to do that. In terms of logic:

```
function post(req,res){
    // Check if the JWT user.id is the same of the endpoint request
    if(req.user._id == req.params.id){ 
       // Here I want to know which is the price plan and to count the Clients that the user has

   }
}
```

In terms of my doubts I have thought in some hypothesis but I truly don't know which one is the best:

- Do a query in the User collection get the price plan, do a query count on the Clients collection validate and then post the new Client.
- Put the User's price plan information in the JWT, do a query count on the user's Clients collection validate and then post the new Client.

These are the two main possible solutions I thought about, but I have serious doubts security and performance wise of which one I should implement/follow.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same doubts. Also if you put anything into your tokens, then when information change, you will have to reissue those tokens (will have to make user login and logout) or implement complex token update logic. Also application evolves: today you need price, tomorrow something else. Changing every time tokens of all users (using it as distributer storage by fact) is not a good idea probably. That's why it is better to keep JWT as short as possible.

Your question is more opinion based, but as my own opinion, I would definitely store in jwt only userId (+ meta information if needed). But not app specific things. Reading from database is the way to go.

Comment: One more time Sergey, I value your opinions very much, you are always on point. Analyzing my specific needs, for this workflow, I need 3 queries, don't you think that is overhead a bit? Yes, my difficulties, for now, are not code wise, but actually architecture and decision wise, it is difficult to get that kind of knowledge alone.

Comment: I personally have a rule, and enforcing it into company, that ANY api response should be given within 300ms. This is top limit, but of course you want as much speed as possible. On the other hand, I personally divide optimisations to micro optimisations and optimisations that makes sense to do. On micro-optimisations you spend your expensive time, but outcome is not worth spent time. One of previous projects, I worked on, made about 400 db queries to render every single page. And still worked. 3 queries in this case not worth even thinking about. But, in your case you decide.